# AWS Cloudformation tying Amplify to bitbucket Repo

Tags: amazon-web-services, bitbucket, aws-cloudformation, aws-amplify

I am using CloudFormation to deploy a multilayer application that includes APIGateways, Lambdas, and all the resources created in Amplify and EB. We built each part of the stack manual. Now we are trying to tie them together in one CloudFormation Template. Where we are tripped up is tying the AWS::Amplify::App to our repository in Bitbucket. The account token setting seems not to be available in our bitbucket instance. Is there another way to tie the amplifying part of the CFN template to that repo? or S3?